# Possible drag and drop files from windows 7 virtual machine in vmware?

Tags: vmware

I currently have a win7 x64 bit appliance. vmware is installed on Ubuntu 12.04. I'm using vmware 4.0.4.

I was told by a friend that you can drag and drop files from vmware straight onto the Ubuntu desktop.

Is this actually possible? If so do i have to install anything to get this working? Or is suppose to work out of the box?

Comment: Do you have virtualbox guest additions installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know and I have only used VMware workstation 6 and above. You need to install VM tools here is a link to your version.

[www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/new_guest_tools_ws.html)